# Hex string validation error

Tags: regex

I was trying to validate 32 hexadecimal characters string using regular expression:

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$
```

however, wrong strings like

```
123456789012345678901234567890gg
```

or

```
1234567890123456789012345678gggg
```

were accepted.  What can be the reason?

Comment: Can you post more complete code? That regex looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a

```
\A[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}\z
```

For all engine not support \z and \A anchors you can use instead:

```
^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$
```

Comment: The common anchors for 'start' and 'end' are what the OP used: `^` and `$`. [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) states `\A` and `\Z` are not supported in all GREP flavors, notably Javascript.

Comment: The OP not specify the engine

Answer (score 0):

Just use a lookahead in your regex to allow only 32 characters,

```
^(?=.{32}$)[0-9A-Fa-f]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bC2eH7/1)

`^[0-9A-Fa-f]+$` allows one or more hexadecimal character. To limit the characters, you need to specify the character limit within a lookahead `(?=...)` or within  set brackets `{}`.

Comment: The OP's expression does "allow one or more hexadecimal characters", but it is bracketed by start and end anchors. Why would they not work?

Comment: His regex works properly http://regex101.com/r/bC2eH7/2 . And also he wants to allow only 32 characters only. Already an user posted a comment regarding that..

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I was wondering if there may be some subtle error because the OP states the original *did* accept the `gg` ending strings. (But there is no need for a lookahead.)